# Write text to PasswordBox using Teststack.White

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm trying to write password to PasswordBox in my WPF application  using TestStack.White

I can find PasswordBox using

`private TextBox Password => Window.Get<TextBox>(1);`

But using `Password.Text = "TestPassword"` doesn't work

I also tried accessing keyboard with

```
Password.ClickAtCenter();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
keyboard.Enter(user.Password);
```

But without any luck.

How do I enter text into PasswordBox using White ?

Comment: there should be `Password` property : `Password.Password = "TestPassword";`

Comment: There is none, cause I'm using White's TextBox class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the method Enter() of the teststack.white.textbox